# How do I change change output csv from 'utf-8-sig' to excel ".csv"?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The code below combines csv files together and creates a new csv file that is 'utf-8-sig'; however, I want it to be ".CSV" for excel. Any suggestions?

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

# Change File Path to personal directory folder
os.chdir("C:/Users")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]


# Using Pandas to combine all files in the list

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "Combined_File.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: ```encoding='utf-8'``` Can you try this?

Comment: You are a lifesaver. That worked.

Comment: I have added it as an answer below. Please mark it as an accepted answer @user17629522

Answer (score 0):

Replace `encoding='utf-8-sig'` with `encoding='utf-8'`